# How to use self signed certificate with an SVN client

Tags: svn, certificates, https

When I access to a SVN repository with HTTPS, I have the follwing error: SSL handshake failed: SSL error: A TLS warning alert has been received. I target a SVN server (with mod_dav) with a self signed certificate.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))